# Find the flow of a vector field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields

**Question**: Let $\mathbb{X}$ be the vector field given by $\mathbb{X}(x,y)=(x,y)$

Compute its flow $\Phi(x,y)$

**Attempt**: We have $\dot{x}(t)=x\therefore$$$\int_{x_0}^{x(t)}dx'=\int_{0}^{t}x(t')dt'$$

$$\left.x'\right|_{x_0}^{x(t)}=\left.\pm e^{t'}\right|_0^t$$

$$x(t)-x_0=\pm e^t-1$$

$$x(t)=\pm e^t+x_0-1$$

And something similar for $y$

Giving flow:

$\Phi(x,y)=(\pm e^t+x-1,\pm e^t+y-1)$

Is this right? Any help or comments would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Well, it doesn't look like a well-defined flow. It doesn't look like $\Phi^{t+s}(x,y) = \Phi^{t}(x,y) \circ \Phi^{s}(x,y)$ holds.

Comment: Yea, even setting $\pm$ to be $+$ doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: vector field generates the system of differential equations:

$$ \dot{{\rm x}} = {\mathbb X}({\rm x}), $$
where ${\rm x} = (x,y)$. This system could be rewritten as

$$ \left \lbrace 
\begin{array}{ccc}
\dot{x} &= x \\
\dot{y} &= y 
\end{array}
 \right . $$

**Note on solving**:

If you solve $\dot{x} = x $ by separation of variables, then you should obtain this

$$ \frac{d x}{dt} = x $$
$$ \frac{d x}{x} = dt $$
$$ \int\limits_{x_0}^{x(t^\ast)} \frac{d x}{x} = \int\limits_{0}^{t^\ast} dt $$
$$ \ln{\frac{x(t^\ast)}{x_0}} = t^\ast  $$
$$ x(t^\ast) = x_0 \cdot e^{t^\ast} $$

Comment: No, my "attempt" at continuing is above, I understand this system and this is what I have tried, the crux of my question is that I am unable to solve this.

Comment: My "attempt" is literally trying and failing to solve this system

Comment: The problem then is that general solution to $\dot{x} = x$ is $x(t) = x_0 \cdot e^t$, not as you've written it.

Comment: I fully understand this now thanks

Answer (score 5):

The vector field $X(x,y):=(x,y)$ encodes the system of ODEs
$$\dot x=x,\quad \dot y=y\ ,$$
which is separated as it stands. Given an initial point $(x_0,y_0)\in{\mathbb R}^2$ the solution is obviously given by
$$x(t)=e^t x_0,\quad y(t)=e^t y_0\qquad(-\infty< t<\infty)\ .$$
In terms of "flow" this means that
$$\Phi_t(x_0,y_0)=e^t(x_0,y_0)\ ,$$
where at the end we may drop the index ${}_0\,$:
$$\Phi_t(x,y)=e^t(x,y)\qquad\bigl((x,y)\in{\mathbb R}^2\bigr)\ .$$
As expected, one has
$$\Phi_{t+s}(x,y)=\Phi_s\circ \Phi_t(x,y)\ .$$

Comment: At the end, why do we drop the index $0$? Is it because initial value changes with respect to $x$? i.e. it is a variable in $x$?

Comment: @Serpenche : $(x_0,y_0)$ was considered "fixed" for the moment; but at the end the flow $\Phi_t(x,y)$ is a function of $t$ and the variable initial point $(x,y)$.